# Property in Amcharts to set balloon alignment?

Tags: amcharts

Does anybody have any idea about the property that changes the alignment of the balloon in amcharts to the one in **figure 1**. By default the balloon alignment in the charts rendered in my project is as in **figure 2**, which sometimes leads to truncation and overflow as shown in **figure 3** if the balloon-text is too long.Hoping that alignment of balloon-text as shown in **figure 1** will help me resolve this issue.
[image]

Comment: Fig 2-3 does not look right at all. Are you running the latest available version? (3.15.1 at this moment) If not, try updating and see if the issue persists.

Comment: The images have been captured  from amcharts demo site. I'm sure they are using the latest available version 3.15.1. http://www.amcharts.com/demos/column-with-rotated-series/ http://www.amcharts.com/demos/stacked-column-chart/

Comment: Thanks. I understand your question now. Answer forthcoming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are probably looking for is a fixed position for the rollover balloon.

This can be achieved by setting [`fixedPosition`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmBalloon#fixedPosition) in your `balloon` settings. I.e.:

```
"balloon": {
    "fixedPosition": true
}
```

Another solution is to enable [chart cursor](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ChartCursor). When chart cursor is enabled all balloons will be adaptively displayed either to the left or to the right of the column center.

Here's a chart cursor that is set up to not display anything beyond a single balloon of the hovered column segment:

```
"chartCursor": {
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "oneBalloonOnly": true
}
```

Finally, the very long continuous strings can be a problem as well. I suggest you use `\n` symbol to add line break points into those. I.e.:

```
"title": "North Americaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
```

Here's a complete working demo:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "legend": {
    "horizontalGap": 10,
    "maxColumns": 1,
    "position": "right",
    "useGraphSettings": true,
    "markerSize": 10
  },
  "dataProvider": [{
    "year": 2003,
    "europe": 2.5,
    "namerica": 2.5,
    "asia": 2.1,
    "lamerica": 0.3,
    "meast": 0.2,
    "africa": 0.1
  }, {
    "year": 2004,
    "europe": 2.6,
    "namerica": 2.7,
    "asia": 2.2,
    "lamerica": 0.3,
    "meast": 0.3,
    "africa": 0.1
  }, {
    "year": 2005,
    "europe": 2.8,
    "namerica": 2.9,
    "asia": 2.4,
    "lamerica": 0.3,
    "meast": 0.3,
    "africa": 0.1
  }],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "stackType": "regular",
    "axisAlpha": 0.3,
    "gridAlpha": 0
  }],
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "labelText": "[[value]]",
    "lineAlpha": 0.3,
    "title": "Europe",
    "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
    "valueField": "europe"
  }, {
    "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "labelText": "[[value]]",
    "lineAlpha": 0.3,
    "title": "North Americaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
    "valueField": "namerica"
  }, {
    "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "labelText": "[[value]]",
    "lineAlpha": 0.3,
    "title": "Asia-Pacific",
    "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
    "valueField": "asia"
  }, {
    "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "labelText": "[[value]]",
    "lineAlpha": 0.3,
    "title": "Latin America",
    "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
    "valueField": "lamerica"
  }, {
    "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "labelText": "[[value]]",
    "lineAlpha": 0.3,
    "title": "Middle-East",
    "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
    "valueField": "meast"
  }, {
    "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "labelText": "[[value]]",
    "lineAlpha": 0.3,
    "title": "Africa",
    "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
    "valueField": "africa"
  }],
  "balloon": {
    "fixedPosition": true,
    "maxWidth": 10000
  },
  "chartCursor": {
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "oneBalloonOnly": true
  },
  "categoryField": "year",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left"
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }

});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.It helped until certain length of the balloon-text. Post that, i'm still facing the issue.Eg : Increase the length of string 'North America' to atleast 60 chars.

Comment: Do you mean that your balloons don't fit into screen? You might want to also set `maxWidth` property to regulate that: http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmBalloon#maxWidth

Comment: Increasing `maxWidth` should help you with that. The default is 220 pixels I think. If content in balloon is bigger than that, the words get wrapped. Increasing this setting should do the trick.

Comment: checked 'maxWidth' = 1000 pixels . Helped avoiding overflow. But truncation (Balloon text box cut at the edge of the chart as shown in figure 3) still persists.

Comment: You might consider enabling chartCursor then. Just add `chartCursor: {}` into your chart config.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84149/discussion-between-priyanka-patil-and-martynasma).